# How to identify a similar or identical sound within an audio file?

Tags: sound, filter, labels

Within a large audio file, I would like to identify sounds that are similar to or identical with exemplary sounds that are used as queries.

I basically need a filter which is defined by one or a few examples.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: This is a job for an intern or tape-op with a pad & pen, not AI.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I don't expect machine learning to be the only solution. I believe that even a simple rule based on standard deviations should do the trick.

Comment: If you need 'code' for a computational rule, you might do better in https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ - they do that kind of thing over there. We push faders & put mics in the right place ;-) Wish you luck.

Comment: If I remember my "signal processing" classes from about 10 years ago, what you are trying to do is, well, signal processing. I think you need a "convolution function", and most likely a Fourier Transform. In other words : you need a mathematician.